# How to call a VBScript sub from Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, vbscript

So, I have success function of a jquery AJAX call. In this call , i am building some HTML dynamically.

The dynamic HTML is built as shown below.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
 $("#tblEmployees").append("<tr class='anEmp'>" +
   "<td>" + response.d[i].EmpID + "</td>" +
   "<td>" + response.d[i].EmpName + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + response.d[i].EmpStatus + "</td>" +
        "</tr>")}
```

Now for the above tr , I need to add an onclick event. In the onclick event , a sub written in vbscript is to be called.

I tried adding the onclick event inline , like so

```
   "<tr onclick='vbscriptSub" + response.d[i].EmpID + "'>"
```

Please keep in mind that I am adding the above line of code during the append itself.Also all lines of code are within the for loop.

The above line of code did not work, since the sub was considered as a jQuery function , and returned a null reference error.

I next tried binding the onlick event to the element with a particular class.

```
   $('.AnEmp').onclick(function(){
       vbscriptSub response.d[i].EmpID  .. compilation error
   });
```

The above line of code gave a compilation error because I was trying to call vbscript sub from jquery.The above line of code is within the for loop shown above.

Please let me know , how I can proceed on this one. I cant change the vbscript sub and neither can I make changes to the jQuery.

Comment: Are you aware of that this will only work in IE browser?

Comment: It will only work in Internet Explorer that is running in compatibility mode. VBS is now disabled by default, and only ever worked in Internet Explorer.

Comment: The application is set to work in IE only. It does not open in Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Its legacy code.So,I cant really get away from vbscript :)

Comment: Well you need to specify your page in compat mode.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could you elaborate?